# Why my angular service variable is undefined?

Tags: angular, service, singleton

i've been trying to get a varaible from one component to another in my code and yet it returns undefined

my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ColorService {

  public color : string;

  constructor() { }
}
```

My app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ColorService } from './core/color.service';

import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { PublicComponent } from './public/public.component';

const routes : Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'user',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'public',
    component: PublicComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'user'
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    PublicComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [
    ColorService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my user component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorService } from '../core/color.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private color: ColorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  colorit(){
    this.color.color = 'blue';
    console.log(this.color.color);
  }

}
```

and the component that should get the color string

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorService } from '../core/color.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-public',
  templateUrl: './public.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./public.component.scss']
})
export class PublicComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private color: ColorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  getColor(){
    console.log(this.color.color);
  }
}
```

yet, everytime that i try to get the color in the public component i get a undefined, even tought it's included within the providers of appModule

Comment: initialize `color` in service with some value and check

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Here's a stackblitz showing it's working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ip61u4

Comment: i'm not sure why it doesn't work, on my other project seems to work fine and i have a login service working in the module without issues, but for some reasons it doesn't work here

Answer (score 2):

For communicating from one component to another component, we can use @Input and @Output emitter properties.

you can update your code as below in PublicComponent.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorService } from '../core/color.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-public',
  templateUrl: './public.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./public.component.scss']
})
export class PublicComponent implements OnInit {
  private _color = '';

  constructor(private color: ColorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  @Input()
  set color(color: string) {
     this._color = color || '<no name set>';
  }

  getColor(){
    console.log(this.color.color);
  }
}
```

Also, add the following line of code in PublicComponent.html file:

```
<app-public [color]="color.color"></app-public>
```

Please make the following changes and let me know if it works fine for you.

Comment: It's a good advise for parent/child communication but here the two components are used in different routes, meaning there is no parent/child communication.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. In this case, we can use get and set methods in service for communication.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component you have method called colorinit where as that method was not declared in the ngoninit lifecycle. So could you confirm whether that method your calling from the component html ?

If not please add that method name inside the lifecycle hook